# How to detect what caused a short time lock after it was released in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, logging, transactions, locking

In Java application I frequently see such errors:
`org.springframework.r2dbc.UncategorizedR2dbcException: executeMany; SQL [select * from table1 where id=:id and column1 <> :a for update]; could not serialize access due to concurrent update; nested exception is io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory$PostgresqlTransientException: [40001] could not serialize access due to concurrent update`

Transaction with query `select * from table1 where id=:id and column1 <> :a for update` was rollbacked.
Transaction isolation level - REPEATABLE READ.
How can I see what has locked this row? Lock is very short (milliseconds).

I see no helpful information in Postgres log and application log.

Comment: If you are trying pessimistic locking and the other locks last mere milliseconds, then you can just catch the exception and try again (maybe in a loop).

Comment: @TheImpaler I already do retries. But I need to know what causes locks because they shouldn't occur. The application has error, but i don't see where it is.

Comment: Are you always locking in the same ordering? That should get rid of deadlocks.

Comment: @TheImpaler I think there are no deadlocks. There are concurrent processes in the apllication which could update the row. I need to know which process locked row, what caused a process which does "select * from table1 where id=:id and column1 <> :a for update" throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not a concurrent lock, but a concurrent data modification. It is perfectly normal to get that error, and if you get it, you should simply repeat the failed transaction.

There is no way to find out which concurrent transaction updated the row unless you log all DML statements.

If you get a lot of these errors, you might consider switching to pessimistic locking using `SELECT ... FOR NO KEY UPDATE`.